# Custom Un-typed WCF Data Service Provider - Identity Column problem

Tags: odata, wcf-data-services

**Problem Background**

I'm building a custom WCF Data Service provider using the [Alex James set of posts](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2010/01/07/data-service-providers-getting-started.aspx) as a basis. My provider works with **un-typed** entities and sits on top of our own ORM Entity definition framework.

Although I've had a lot of success covering all of the main requirements we've got, I've hit a wall when it comes to defining auto-generated properties in the exposed $metadata page.  (The $metadata page is automatically generated by .NET Framework from the internal representation of the metadata - I don't define the document content directly).

Examining the $metadata page for a standard WCF Data Service on top of a simple EF model, you get something like:

```
<Property Name="ID" Type="Edm.Int16" Nullable="false" p8:StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity"/>
```

with the *StoreGeneratedPattern* attribute letting the consumers know about the auto-generation for the given field.

**The Specific Problem**

My problem is that, in my custom **un-typed** world, I can't get find the hook to get the *StoreGeneratedPattern* attribute into my metadata.  I'm looking around *IDataServiceMetadataProvider* and the *System.Data.Services.** namespaces but I'm completely stumped.

Comment: Hello stax i am in the same boar and begining to contemplate going down this path, wondering how it went for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way currently to specify custom annotations with untyped providers in WCF data services. This is a known feature that is getting asked by a lot of customers. Here's the list to the voting site where you can vote for your favorite feature: http://data.uservoice.com/forums/72027-wcf-data-services-feature-suggestions

Thanks
Pratik